# Find text in string, case insensitive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a small script to check my expenses. In the description I look for a term. So I search within a string (like a supermarket brand). Unfortunately, it can only check case sensitive. How to fix this? I want to search within the string independent of the case. The search terms can be upper of lower case, easy to adjust.

```
for (i in uitgaven)
{

   for(n=0;n<data.length;++n)// iterate row by row and examine data in column A
   { 

     if(data[n][3].toString().match(uitgaven[i][0])==uitgaven[i][0]){ data[n][4] = uitgaven[i][1]
   };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just substitute this:

```
data[n][3].toString().toUpperCase()===uitgaven[i][0].toUpperCase()
```

for this:

```
data[n][3].toString().match(uitgaven[i][0])==uitgaven[i][0]
```